# How to get TFS(Team Foundation Server) work items(bug,task) details using REST api?

Tags: rest, tfs, azure-devops

I have been working on TFS REST api, to get the work items(bug,task) details.
I have used GET method,

```
GET https://shankarsam.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/New-1/_apis/wit/queries/Shared%20Queries/My%20Bugs?$depth=1&api-version=2.2
```

It shows the following output

```
 "id": "e7731d7b-10d2-441f-899f-b081e4008b21",
    "name": "My Bugs",
    "path": "Shared Queries/My Bugs",
    "createdBy":
    {
        "id": "7bb24a89-a490-4ffa-9047-252e4a2b274b",
        "displayName": "kalaisankaran B "
    },
    "createdDate": "2016-07-15T05:30:18.34Z",
    "lastModifiedBy":
    {
        "id": "7bb24a89-a490-4ffa-9047-252e4a2b274b",
        "displayName": "kalaisankaran B "
    },
    "lastModifiedDate": "2016-07-15T05:30:18.34Z",
    "isPublic": true,
```

I couldn't get all bug details.
In case of UI, I have navigated to Shared Queries -> My Bugs -> Bugs has been listed. Please see the attached screen shot. 
[image]

Comment: You get all the all the Fields by default, which details are you missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution. If we need to display all the Bugs or Tasks which is associated in the project. Use the following rest api call.

```
  POST https://<Account Name>.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/<Project Name>/_apis/wit/wiql?api-version=1.0
  Ex :
  POST https://shankarsam.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/New-1/_apis/wit/wiql?api-version=1.0
```

Header :

```
  Content-Type  application/json
```

Request Body Ex :

```
  {
  "query": "Select [System.Id], [System.Title], [System.State] From WorkItems Where [System.WorkItemType] = 'Bug'"
  }
```

Need to display Task item means , try this `[System.WorkItemType] = 'Task'`

Display Bug or Task related work items, Repo's try this :

```
  GET https://<Account Name>.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/_apis/wit/workitems?id=<Issue ID>&$expand=all&api-version=1.0
  Ex:
  GET https://shankarsam.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/_apis/wit/workitems?id=23&$expand=all&api-version=1.0
```

Answer (score 3):

The best place to start with this is to look at the [REST API Documentation](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/wit/wiql).  It covers this exact scenario with some useful examples.

I see that you have retrieved the query hierarchy, and with that you can run a query and then get the work items.

From your call above, I will use the "My Bugs" query as the example.

```
GET https://shankarsam.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/New-1/_apis/wit/wiql/7731d7b-10d2-441f-899f-b081e4008b21
```

Which will return query results:

```
{
  "queryType": "flat",
  "workItems": [
    {
      "id": 300,
      "url": "https://fabrikam-fiber-inc.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/_apis/wit/workItems/300"
    }
  ]
}
```

From that, you can use the id property in the result to get the work item:

```
GET https://shankarsam.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/New-1/_apis/wit/workItems/1
```

Which will return the work item.