# How to get all work items in TFS 2013 using REST API

Tags: tfs, tfs-workitem

I need to  retrieve all work items in TFS 2015.2 using REST API

I have referred below link from Microsoft

https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/work/track/using-queries

Below is the similar url pattern I used,

```
http://fabrikam:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/q.aspx?pname=FabrikamFiber&wiql=SELECT [System.ID], [System.Title], [System.State] FROM WorkItems WHERE [System.TeamProject]='FabrikamFiber' AND [System.WorkItemType]='Bug'
```

However this url end-up with nothing but error

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hhiTk.png)

Error
The page you are looking for is currently unavailable.

TF400914: The specified team, q.aspx, either does not exist or you do not have access to it.

Please be kind enough to show some light to overcome this issue.

Comment: You need to  retrieve all work items in TFS 2015.2, even though you are using TFS2013 in the title and tag. Which TFS version are you actually using ?

Comment: Hi Patrick , its 2015.2 . sorry about confusion and thank a lot for great solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note TFS 2015 require that you **encode the WIQL portion** of the URL syntax. You can use any URL encoder tool to encode your URL.

**TFS 2015 syntax**

```
https://{ServerName}/{CollectionName}/{TeamProjectName}/_workitems?_a=query&wiql={Encoded WorkItemQueryLanguage]
```

For example, the following hyperlink lists the ID, title, and state of all bugs under the FabrikamFiber/Web area path hosted on the fabrikam server and it's **encoded url**.

```
http://fabrikam:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/FabrikamFiber/_workitems?_a=query&wiql=SELECT%20%5BSystem.ID%5D%2C%20%5BSystem.Title%5D%2C%20%5BSystem.State%5D%20FROM%20WorkItems%20WHERE%20%5BSystem.TeamProject%5D%3D'FabrikamFiber'%20AND%20%5BSystem.WorkItemType%5D%3D'Bug'%20AND%20%5BSystem.AreaPath%5D%3D'FabrikamFiber%5CWeb'%20%20
```

According to your url, seems you are still using TFS 2013 syntax, if you need to retrieve all work items in TFS 2015.2. Please use TFS2015 syntax instead.

---

If you need to retrieve all work items in TFS2013. The easiest way to define a hyperlink is to create a query that matches what you want and then copy the URL for the query.  Create the same query in web portal/team explorer to narrow down the issue to see if you are able to get all work items. And copy the url directly to double check your url format.

Comment: Thanks a lot Patrick, I need to get all 'Bug' type work items (using query) in REST API , but there is no example to get work items without defining ID(im referring https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/wit/work-items) . Is it possible to achieve this task? If so can I have example ?

Comment: @Lalindu It's possible, you just need to  use `[System.WorkItemType] = 'Bug'` in the request body. More detail info please take a look at this similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38524918/how-to-get-tfsteam-foundation-server-work-itemsbug-task-details-using-rest-a